# Show the content based on link click. And hide previously selected

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to show the content based on link click. and hide the content which was previously selected.

Any way to do it?
Note : I dont want to change the markup.

### [Here is jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Dipak1991/RZXfF/)

**html:**

```
<ul class="nav nav-stacked" id="nav-stacked">
    <li class="active"><a href="#" onclick="show_content('dashboard', this)"><i class="fa fa-dashboard fa-fw"></i>Dashboard</a>

    </li>
    <li id="vollist-container" class="menu open"><a href="#" class="menu-toggle"><i class="fa fa-sort-alpha-asc fa-fw"></i>Volumes<i class="caret"></i></a> 
        <ul id="vol-list" class="submenu">
            <li> <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="show_content('vol1', this)">
                    <span>vol1</span>
                </a>

            </li>
            <li> <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="show_content('vol2', this)">
                    <span>vol2</span>
                </a>

            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
<div id="content">
    <div id="dashboard" class='show'>dashboard</div>
    <div id="volumes">
        <div id="vol1" class="hide">vol 1</div>
        <div id="vol2" class="hide">vol 2</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**jQuery:**

```
function show_content(id, element) {
    var children = $("#content").children();
    children.filter(function () {
        return $(this).css('display') == 'block';

    }).hide();

    $("#" + id).parent().css('display') == 'none' ? $("#" + id).parent().show() : null;
    $("#" + id).toggleClass('hide');
}
```

Answer (score -1):

This function does what you need:

```
function show_content(id, element) {
    $('#content > div').hide();
    $('#' + id).show();
}
```

Notes:

- You do not need the .show and .hide CSS classes
- You still need to hide all the content divs on page load either via CSS or via jQuery.
- The element parameter is not necessary.
- jQuery offers more elegant ways to solve this problem, but the function above should answer your question.

Answer (score -1):

```
<script>
function showSomething()
{
    $("#div1").hide();
    $("#div2").show();

</script>
```

Around your div:

```
<a href="Javascript:showSomething();">
<div></div>
</a>
```